# Finding a specific number within a comma separated list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database which has a field containing some comma separated values like `1,8,3,54,5,19,9....`. I want to select only those rows where `2` doesn't exists.

The query below is used for finding all fields containing the number `2` in the attachedCompanyIDs column. However, I want to find all rows where that number *doesn't* exist, but I don't know how to use `find_in_set` in this case. Can any one please help me?

```
 SELECT name FROM company
 WHERE orderID = 1 AND FIND_IN_SET(2, attachedCompanyIDs);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM company
WHERE orderID = 1 AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(2, attachedCompanyIDs);
```

or

```
SELECT name FROM company
WHERE orderID = 1 AND FIND_IN_SET(2, attachedCompanyIDs) = 0;
```